# Correlation between menstrual period and lunar revolution

Tags: reproduction

Is it just a coincidence that the the length of the entire menstrual cycle from one flow to the other lasts almost exactly as one lunar month?

Comment: Do you mean if there is any correlation between day and night (specifically light as a zeitgeber) on menstrual cycle? Yes. There is.